# libxml-ruby failed to load at x86_64

Tags: ruby, elf, libxml2, libxml-ruby

We are having problem with libxml-ruby gem at the server side
Possible because it uses x86_64 architecture:

$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-228-171-64 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen-ec2-v1.0 #1 SMP Tue Sep 1 10:25:30 EDT 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
require 'libxml'
LoadError: /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.4/lib/libxml_ruby.so: invalid ELF header - /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.4/lib/libxml_ruby.so
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.4/lib/libxml_ruby.so
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.4/lib/libxml.rb:9
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /usr/local/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from (irb):1
```

gem version 1.1.4

Reinstalling the gem doesn't help
Can somebody suggest what to do?

Comment: I've tried installing version 1.1.3 it gives the same error too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try reverting your libxml-ruby gem version to 1.1.3

Comment: I've tried installing version 1.1.3 it gives the same error too

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact same issue in a Centos....Aparently there is a problem with gem version 1.1.4 and 64 bit machines. Head over to [rubyfourge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=494) and dowload version 1.1.3.

http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=494

download the .gem an then just run:

```
gem install libxml-ruby-1.1.3.gem
```

On the console. I hope this helps

Comment: Although version 1.1.4 was working fine on my local 64 bit Mac OS X, I had the same problem when deploying to a 64bit Ubuntu Linux. Downgrading to 1.1.3 solved this issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, I was having the same issue in ubuntu, and what worked was to install the libxml dev package, as detailed [here](http://www.gregbenedict.com/2008/01/25/compile-errors-installing-ruby-xslt-and-libxml-ruby-gems/)

for Ubuntu, use apt-get instead of yum:
% sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev

then the install of libxml-ruby gem works like a charm.

Comment: Works on raspberry too by the way!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason on Linux, sometimes gem gets confused and installs the Windows DLL for libxml-ruby.  You can verify this by doing a `file` on (ruby lib path)/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.4/lib/libxml_ruby.so and it says that libxml_ruby.so is a Windows PE DLL.

The way I've found to work around this is to force the platform, i.e:

`gem install libxml-ruby --platform ruby`

Comment: For me, I had to run `gem install libxml-ruby -v 1.1.4 --platform x86_64` as there is no pure ruby version.

Comment: I have tried `gem install libxml-ruby -v 1.1.4 --platform x86_64` still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem today, and it turned out that rubygems had installed the Windows dll instead of an ELF *.so.  We are running a fairly old version of Rubygems (1.3.7), but reinstalling the gem somehow solved the problem.  Not sure if platform detection in that version of Rubygems or something?